# If I assign a POD struct to another POD struct, is there any memory leak?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
struct Vertex
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

Vertex makeVertex(int xpos, int ypos)
{
  Vertex tmp = {xpos, ypos};
  return tmp;
}
```

Would I get a memory leak if I did this?:

```
Vertex a = makeVertex(30,40);
a = makeVertex(5, 102);
```

Comment: No. You only get memory leaks if you misuse dynamic allocation.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes or with a concurrent access

Comment: You must see [what is a memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373854/what-is-a-memory-leak).

Comment: Ok - so no memory leak. Are there any other problems with assigning a POD struct to another POD struct like this?

Comment: @BeeBand No dynamic alloc, no memory leak.

Comment: @beeBand [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627/how-do-you-detect-avoid-memory-leaks-in-your-unmanaged-code) isn't exactly relevant but you can use it.

Comment: @user2485710 Can you elaborate how you can get a memory leak that doesn't involve misusing dynamic allocation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is perfectly safe.

Memory leaks are caused by (mis)using pointers and memory allocations (typically calls to `new` that aren't followed by calls to `delete`, but more complex cases are often where the real problems occur - e.g. not completing the "rule of three (or five)" when dealing with classes that have calls to `new`).

And of course when using the C style calls to `malloc` and siblings the code should have a corresponding `free` call.

Comment: +1; yes I know the comments also contain an answer but I don't like the practice of answering 'simple' questions in comments on this site.