# Is this malloc/free pair leaking memory?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I'm new to C.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void demo() {
    char* s = malloc(10);
    strcpy(s, "foo");
    free(s);
}

int main()
{
    demo();
}
```

Will this program leak memory with several bytes?

Comment: Is your concern about the last 6 characters of `s`? (past the end of `"foo"`) Worry not, `free` will free the whole allocation of `s`, regardless of how you used it or what you put in it

Comment: `malloc` allocates a little bit of extra memory, and uses it to store the size of the allocation.  This is a significant C design mistake, IMHO.

Comment: It doesn't. Try running it in valgrind, you'll have a message if there is a memory leak.

Comment: Is the actual question here "what is a memory leak"?

Comment: The rule is this: each pointer value returned by `malloc()` or another allocation function must subsequently be passed to `free()`, exactly once, if the allocated memory is to be released before program termination.  If your program obeys that rule with respect to every dynamic allocation then it will not leak memory.  There is some debate over whether the definition of "memory leak" should allow for unfreed memory if that is still accessible at program termination, but that particular wrinkle is not relevant to your program.

Comment: @Lundin The actually question is "how does free work" - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1957125) describes it: "When you malloc a block, it actually allocates a bit more memory than you asked for. This extra memory is used to store information such as the size of the allocated block ... When you free your pointer, it uses that address to find the special information ..."

Comment: @ntk138 That's one way to implement a heap allocation, but there are others too, such as a pointer look-up table storing address and size. Such an implementation is an access/allocation speed optimization at the cost of memory use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Will this program leak memory with several bytes?

**No**.

`free(s)` will de-allocate all the memory that was dynamically allocated by `char* s = malloc(10);` in this example.

As @Alexander commented: "Is your concern about the last 6 characters of `s`? (past the end of `"foo"`) Worry not, `free()` will free the whole allocation of `s`, regardless of how you used it or what you put in it"

---

Good read: [What is a memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373854/what-is-a-memory-leak)

Comment: I think the strcpy, will actually leak.

Comment: @hetepeperfan can you elaborate? Why do you think that the strcpy will leak?

Comment: @hetepeperfan - Why would it? `"foo"` is null-terminated, and the target buffer has sufficient room for what's being copied to it.

Comment: Sorry, I read strdup, my mistake :-(

Answer (score 4):

The function malloc is declared the following way

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

It knows nothing about how the allocated memory will be used and what will be stored in it.

The only parameter `size` specifies the size of the allocated memory.

To free the allocated memory all you need is to pass the pointer to the allocated memory.

So there is neither memory leak in this code snippet

```
char* s = malloc(10);
strcpy(s, "foo");
free(s);
```

The pointer `s` is point to the allocated memory and this pointer is used to free the allocated memory. And it is entirely unimportant whether something was stored in the allocated memory or not.

If you want to reduce or enlarge the allocated memory when use another standard C function `realloc`. The function keeps the data stored in the previously allocated memory according to the newly allocated size of the extent of memory.

For example, you could write

```
char* s = malloc(10);
const char *foo = "foo";
strcpy( s, foo );

size_t n = strlen( s );

char *tmp = realloc( s, n + 1 );

if ( tmp != NULL ) s = tmp;

puts( s );

free( s );
```

Comment: @pmacfarlane Oh, thanks. It was a typo due to copy and paste.:)